# Converting VBA With statements to Python in pywin32

Tags: python, vba, ms-word, pywin32

I am trying to convert`With` statements in VBA to Python, and more specifically this one (for MS Word):

```vb
With Selection.FormFields(1)
    .Name = "Widget_name"
    .EntryMacro = ""
    .ExitMacro = ""
    .Enabled = True
    .OwnHelp = False
    .HelpText = ""
    .OwnStatus = False
    .StatusText = ""
    With .TextInput
        .EditType Type:=wdRegularText, Default:="ComboBoxEdit", Format:= _
            ""
        .Width = 0
    End With
End With
```

I am trying to edit the value of a given bookmark (`Widget_name`) and update its value to `"ComboBoxEdit"`.

I am a bit lost on how to do that in Python.

For example, shall I use the `with` as well? And what to do of the `.xxx = yyy` on the lines after?

I very naively tried this, but this gently tells you that `Name` is not an argument ;)

```py
with word.Selection.FormFields(1, Name="Widget_name"):
    ...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you might not have to use an equivalent of `With` statement.

The following function is working to update some forms (and update the whole document to match the changes.

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Dict, List, Union

import win32com.client as win32

def update_bookmarks(path: Union[Path, str], new_values: Dict[str, str]) -> List[str]:
    """Update Bookmarks if a given document and return names of updated forms"""
    word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Word.Application")  # type: ignore
    doc = word.Documents.Open(str(Path(path).absolute()))
    doc.Activate()

    # We will select the whole document to be sure to get all the forms
    selection = word.Selection
    selection.WholeStory()

    updated: List[str] = []
    for field in word.Selection.FormFields:
        name = field.Name
        current_value = field.TextInput.Default
        value = new_values.get(name, None)

        if value and value != current_value:
            field.TextInput.Default = value
            updated.append(name)

    # If we have updated at least one form, we will update the whole document
    # And then we will select just this last form to keep it clean
    if updated:
        selection.WholeStory()
        selection.Fields.Update()

    selection.Collapse()

    return updated


new_values = {"Widget_name": "SuperWidget15"}
update_bookmarks(output_path, new_values)
```